# How to dynamically load a native dll in c# .net standard?

Tags: c#, .net-standard, loadlibrary

I want to use something similar to NativeLibrary.TryLoad for a native dll in dot net standard. But I cannot find a method for it. Is there a good way to do this?

I know a can do things like

[DllImport(@"alib.dll")]
internal extern static int func();

but that is not what I want in this case. Im tracking a bug that cause a library to sometimes not load (from inside a dll that Im calling). So I want to preload it in my program and see if that helps.

Comment: You have to [pinvoke loadlibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10516597/17034).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw).

Comment: The question is about c#.

Comment: Could you give a sketch / minimal guidance on how it would be user in OP's context? Currently this answer is nearly just a link.

Comment: It solved my problem. I pinvoked loadlibrary in kernel32 as suggested in the link by Hans above.